# Traversing Different Levels of Nested Dictionary Depending on Condition

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some nested Python dictionary like `my_dict[year][month][day] = some_value`. 
Each sub level is a dictionary.

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[year] = {}
my_dict[year][month] = {}
...
```

Depending on some condition, I want to traverse the nested dictionary up to a certain level. Initially I was using nested `for` loops. e.g.,

```
for year in my_dict:
    for month in my_dict[year]:
        print(my_dict[year][month])
```

or if I wanted up to `day`

```
for year in my_dict:
    for month in my_dict[year]:
        for day in my_dict[year][month]:
            print(my_dict[year][month][day])
```

But this seemed repetitive, so I opted for a generator.

```
def my_generator(my_dict, interval):

    if interval == 'day':
        for year in my_dict:
            for month in my_dict[year]:
                for day in my_dict[year][month]:
                    yield year, month, day

    elif interval == 'month':
        for year in my_dict:
            for month in my_dict[year]:
                yield year, month

    etc...
```

Using this approach, I generate an iterator which matches the given condition, e.g. if I want to traverse the nested dict up to `day`.

```
iterator = my_generator(my_dict, interval='day')
for year, month, day in iterator:
    print(my_dict[year][month][day])
```

The above does seem to simplify the code slightly.

Is there a better way of traversing this data structure? What are the best practices here?